# How do I find a file given its basename and retrieve its filetype in a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm writing my first bash script as part of homework and given covid 19 we haven't been able to go over some of this stuff in class (and I'm not doing well googling).

I am writing a script that takes user input and searches the cd to find a file with the name of $userInput. If found the script will determine if the file is a "normal file" (.txt for example) or if the file is a directory. How can I gather this information?

Here is my code currently:

```
#! /bin/bash

$userInput 
echo "Enter a file name. Empty to exit."
while [ 1 ]
do
    echo "Please input a file name:"
    read userInput
    if [ "$userInput" == "" ]; then
        exit
    else
        echo $userInput
    fi
done
```

I have the looping and getting user input down, what am I missing here?

Comment: `if [[ -f "$userInput" ]]` to check if input is file.   `if [[ -d "$userInput" ]]`; to check if input is directory.

Comment: but if I have a file "textFile.txt" and I search for "textFile" I need to be able to give the output "textFile.txt is a regular file."

With your suggestion it will only find said file if I include the extension as well.

Comment: Check `ls Textfile*`

Comment: The `[ 1 ]` check if the string `1` has non zero length, and because it does, it returns with a zero exit status (success). Endless loops are usually done with `while :` or `while true`

Comment: @Starskii : Of course the user should enter the exact file name he is interested. If you want to beef up your project a bit, you could allow the user to enter e glob pattern (say `text*.txt`), and you would then search the whole list of files matching this pattern, and classify each single one. This would be the next step; first, solve the simple part, before extending it.

Answer (score 0):

```
if cd $userInput*; then
   cd ..
   echo "It is a directory."
else
   # the cd will do the rest of informing for you
fi
```

I also strongly suggest to turn this into a file and get user input in command line, like this:

`bash ./yourcode.sh filename`

Inside your code:

```
if cd $1*; then
    cd ..
    echo "It is a directory."
else
    # the cd will do the rest of informing for you
fi
```

**EDITED: EXTRA**

Continue here if you really wanna understand what happened. In bash, every command/function by default returns a value that informs the kernel whether it terminated successfully or something went wrong, for sake of simplicity, we will just assume it returns `true` if successful and `false` if not, here I used this piece of info with the function `cd` which changes the current directory to the one specified, if the change happened successfully, it will return `true` which then I will capture in my `if` statement to execute the code, which consists of returning to the original directory (`cd ..`) and saying to the user it was a directory. 
Otherwise, `cd` will return false and will tell you itself what happened, was it a file or was it nonexistent, and the `*` (a wildcard) exists to find whatever  extension it might have or even doesn't have. I hope this helps, cheers!

Comment: You are testing whether we can `cd` into $userInput, which is different from asking whether $userInput is a directory. It is easy to create a directory where you can not cd into, and there are also cases where $userInput is not a directory, but you still can cd into it (this happens, if $userInput is a symlink to a directory).

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to classify an entry. For instance,

```
[[ -f $filename ]]
```

tests for regular files,

```
[[ -d $filename ]]
```

tests for directories, and there are other tests too where you can test for symlinks, or whether you have read/write/execute permissions. You find the list of available file test operators [here](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html).